# How to encrypt a byte array with Crypto++

Tags: c++, arrays, encryption, crypto++

How can I encrypt a byte array with Crypto++'s RSA implementation? I already found an example for strings. But I can't find a good example how to do the same for a byte array.

This is my first attempt:

```
//dataSize:     Size of data that is going to be send
//dataToSend    Bytes to send to the user
//seedPool      is an AutoSeededRandomPool

CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor encryptor(publicKey);

int size = 64000; 
byte * cipher = new byte(size);

CryptoPP::ArraySink* test = new CryptoPP::ArraySink(cipher, size);
CryptoPP::ArraySource as((byte*)dataToSend, dataSize, true, new CryptoPP::PK_EncryptorFilter(seedPool, encryptor, test));

int newDataSize = test->TotalPutLength();
unsigned int bytesSend = ::send(socketLink, (char *)(cipher), (int)newDataSize, 0);

delete[] cipher;
```

This doesn't work. `TotalPutLength` will always return 0 but there is data put in cipher.

What is a safe way to implement this? I don't want to be vulnerable for buffer overflows or any other attack.

Answer (score 3):

> byte * cipher = new byte(size);

I believe this should be:

```
byte * cipher = new byte[size];
```

Otherwise, I think you get one byte initialized to 6400 (which is truncated to 0x00).

---

> CryptoPP::ArraySink * test = new CryptoPP::ArraySink(cipher, size);

This is kind of different. You can stay out of the memory manager if you'd like:

```
 CryptoPP::ArraySink test(cipher, size);
```

---

> int newDataSize = test->TotalPutLength();

<strike>I've never used `TotalPutLength`, and I did not see it documented on a `BufferedTransformation` or `Sink`. So I don't really have any advice on what its returning.</strike>

`TotalPutLength` is OK to use. An `ArraySink` could return the wrong value *if* the sink was full. It would happen if the array was fixed and too small for all the data. We cleared that issue at Crypto++ 5.6.3 or 5.6.4.

If you want to count the number of bytes processed (even if the sink cannot store they bytes), then you can also use a [`MeterFilter`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/MeterFilter):

```
byte data[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 };

string encoded;
MeterFilter meter( new StringSink( encoded ) );

ArraySource( data, sizeof( data ), true,
    new HexEncoder(
        new Redirector( meter ),
        true /*UCase*/, 2 /*Group*/,
        " " /*Separator*/
    )
);

cout << "processed " << meter.GetTotalBytes() << " bytes" << endl;
cout << encoded << endl;
```

Output:

```
Processed 23 bytes
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
```

---

> How can you encrypt a byte array with Cryptopp RSA implementation

Now we're talking ;) Try this from the Crypto++ wiki on [RSA Encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Encryption_Schemes).

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Generate keys
AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

InvertibleRSAFunction params;
params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize( rng, 1536 );

RSA::PrivateKey privateKey( params );
RSA::PublicKey publicKey( params );

string plain="RSA Encryption", cipher, recovered;

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Encryption
RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e( publicKey );

StringSource ss1( plain, true,
    new PK_EncryptorFilter( rng, e,
        new StringSink( cipher )
    ) // PK_EncryptorFilter
 ); // StringSource

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Decryption
RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor d( privateKey );

StringSource ss2( cipher, true,
    new PK_DecryptorFilter( rng, d,
        new StringSink( recovered )
    ) // PK_DecryptorFilter
 ); // StringSource

assert( plain == recovered );
```