# Encrypt/Decrypt byte array Crypto++

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I am trying to encrypt a byte array using AES. I have been able to encrypt strings and files no problem, however byte arrays seem to not be working for me. I pass in a byte array to be encrypted, for ease of testing I just pass in a generated AES key by crypto++ (bArrayToEncrypt). The encryption appears to be working but then the decryption does work at all. I also found it strange that the encryption has a large amount of duplicate characters. What I am doing wrong here??

I saw a similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814236/how-to-encrypt-a-byte-array-with-crypto), but it was pertaining to RSA
 as well as the example provided encrypts strings which I already have up a running.

### How functions are called:

```cpp
   size_t ksize = CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH;
   size_t vsize = CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE;

   byte key[ksize];
   byte testArray[ksize];
   byte encryptedksize];
   byte decrypted[ksize];
   byte iv[vsize];

   //generate key & iv, then generate a random byte array to encrypt/decrypt
   CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
   prng.GenerateBlock(key, ksize);
   prng.GenerateBlock(iv, vsize);
   prng.GenerateBlock(testArray, ksize);


   encrypt_barray(key, ksize, iv, vsize, testArray, ksize, encrypted);

   //printed results here

   decrypt_barray(key, ksize, iv, vsize, encrypted, ksize, decrypted);

   //printed results here
```

### Encrypt_barray

```cpp
void encrypt_barray(byte* key, 
                    size_t kSize,
                    byte* iv, 
                    size_t ivSize, 
                    byte* bArrayToEncrypt,
                    size_t bArraySize,
                    byte* encrypted) {

   CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption e;
   e.SetKeyWithIV(key, kSize, iv, ivSize);

   CryptoPP::ArraySource(key, true,
      new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(e, new CryptoPP::ArraySink(encrypted, bArraySize)));
}
```

### Decrypt_barray

```cpp
void decrypt_barray(byte* key,
                    size_t kSize,
                    byte* iv,
                    size_t ivSize,
                    byte* bArrayToDecrypt,
                    size_t bArraySize,
                    byte* decrypted) {

   CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption d;
   d.SetKeyWithIV(keyFromHash, kfhSize, iv1, iv1Size);

   CryptoPP::ArraySource(keyToDecrypt, true,
      new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(d, new CryptoPP::ArraySink(decrypted, bArraySize)));
}
```

### Output:

```
 Encrypted: ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠E1A2AFC5D820ADF7
7DB656DEF3245570╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╨Ñ♫

Decrypted: ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠E
1A2AFC5D820ADF77DB656DEF3245570╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╨Ñ♫
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `ArraySink` is the wrong tool for the job. You cannot get the actual size of the ciphertext from the encryption operation. Then, during decryption, you are flying blind because you don't know what size to use with the `ArraySource`. Consider switching to a `std::string` or a `ByteQueue`. Also see [SecByteBlockSink](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SecByteBlockSink) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: Also, `E1A2AFC5D820ADF77DB656DEF3245570` and `E1A2AFC5D820ADF77DB656DEF3245570` almost look like a concatenation memory locations (i.e., pointers) to me. You should probably show the way you are calling `encrypt_barray` and `decrypt_barray`.

Comment: @jww I went ahead and added how I am calling those 2 functions. Thanks!

Comment: How would I go about incorporating a ByteQueue into these functions?

Comment: The ciphertext will be larger than `testArray[ksize]` due to the mode of operation and PKCS padding. `ArraySink` will store up to `ksize` bytes, and then stop writing to the array.

Comment: @jww That would make sense. So then you mentioned i should change it to use a ByteQueue. How would I go about incorporating a ByteQueue into these functions? Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the way to do things using `ArraySource` and `ArraySink`. The `Redirector` ensures the `ArraySink` survives so you can call `TotalPutLength`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "hex.h"
#include "aes.h"
using namespace CryptoPP;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  byte key[AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH];
  byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
  vector<byte> plain, cipher, recover;
  HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(cout));

  memset(key, 0x00, sizeof(key));
  memset(iv, 0x00, sizeof(iv));

  string str("Attack at dawn!");
  std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(plain));

  cout << "Plain text: ";
  encoder.Put(plain.data(), plain.size());
  encoder.MessageEnd();
  cout << endl;

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption enc;
  enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

  // Make room for padding
  cipher.resize(plain.size()+AES::BLOCKSIZE);
  ArraySink cs(&cipher[0], cipher.size());

  ArraySource(plain.data(), plain.size(), true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(enc, new Redirector(cs)));

  // Set cipher text length now that its known
  cipher.resize(cs.TotalPutLength());

  cout << "Cipher text: ";
  encoder.Put(cipher.data(), cipher.size());
  encoder.MessageEnd();
  cout << endl;

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption dec;
  dec.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

  // Recovered text will be less than cipher text
  recover.resize(cipher.size());
  ArraySink rs(&recover[0], recover.size());

  ArraySource(cipher.data(), cipher.size(), true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(dec, new Redirector(rs)));

  // Set recovered text length now that its known
  recover.resize(rs.TotalPutLength());

  cout << "Recovered text: ";
  encoder.Put(recover.data(), recover.size());
  encoder.MessageEnd();
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Running the program results in:

```
$ ./test.exe
Plain text: 41747461636B206174206461776E21
Cipher text: 85928E5511BFE9E6EE235BCACC4894D4
Recovered text: 41747461636B206174206461776E21
```

---

Here's the example using `ByteQueue`. The `Redirector` helps chain the pipeline together because a `ByteQueue` is a `BufferedTransformation`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "hex.h"
#include "aes.h"
using namespace CryptoPP;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  byte key[AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH];
  byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
  HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(cout));

  memset(key, 0x00, sizeof(key));
  memset(iv, 0x00, sizeof(iv));

  ByteQueue plain, cipher, recover;
  string str("Attack at dawn!");
  plain.Put(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(str.data()), str.size());

  cout << "Plain text: ";
  plain.CopyTo(encoder);
  encoder.MessageEnd();
  cout << endl;

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption enc;
  enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

  StreamTransformationFilter f1(enc, new Redirector(cipher));
  plain.CopyTo(f1);
  f1.MessageEnd();

  cout << "Cipher text: ";
  cipher.CopyTo(encoder);
  encoder.MessageEnd();
  cout << endl;

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption dec;
  dec.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

  StreamTransformationFilter f2(dec, new Redirector(recover));
  cipher.CopyTo(f2);
  f2.MessageEnd();

  cout << "Recovered text: ";
  recover.CopyTo(encoder);
  encoder.MessageEnd();
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

It also results in:

```
skylake:cryptopp$ ./test.exe
Plain text: 41747461636B206174206461776E21
Cipher text: 85928E5511BFE9E6EE235BCACC4894D4
Recovered text: 41747461636B206174206461776E21
```

Comment: What an awesome answer! Really appreciate this cause now I also get to learn why it's the correct way. Thanks again!